# How can I display an array of strings but selecting the index of the string in the array for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my problem.
I have a table for roles with two columns id and name.
The column id is linked through foreign key to the column role_id in the users table. The columns id and role_id are of type integer.
In the table roles I have these 4 records:

```
id name
-- ----
1  owner
2  doctor
3  receptionist
4  customer
```

For user I have a form to edit the privileges like admin and role_id.
I want to display values like the role names but when I click on the Submit button I want the id or role_id integer value to be used to update the customer.

The user_controller.rb file:

```
  def show
    @user = User.includes(:role).find(params[:id])
    #@role = @user.role
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.includes(:role).find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.includes(:role).find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "User Priviladges Updated"
      #log_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role_id, 
      :password, :password_confirmation, :admin)
    end
```

The edit.html.erb file:

```
<h1>Edit User Privileges</h1>
<strong><%= "Name: " %></strong><%=@user.name%>
<br>
<strong><%= "Email: " %></strong><%=@user.email%>
<br>
<strong><%= "Role: " %></strong><%=@user.role.name%>
<br>
<strong><%= "Role ID: " %></strong><%=@user.role_id%>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :admin %>
    <%= f.label :admin %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role_id %>
    <%=f.select :role_id, options_for_select([1,2,3,4], f.object.role_id), :include_blank => false %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button 'Submit', class: "btn btn-sm btn-info" %>
  </div>
  <br>
  <strong><%= link_to 'Back', :back %></strong>
<% end %>
```

The code works and values for role_id are updated correctly. However how I can display string in the drop down select list instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is:

```
<%= f.select :role_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Role.order("id"), :id, :name, @user.try(:role_id)) %>
```